# Why is std::is_aggregate<T> an aggregate?

Tags: c++, std, c++17, type-traits

I always was under the impression that  types like `std::is_same`, `std::is_void`, or `std::is_aggregate` are supposed to inherit from `std::integral_constant`, or more specifically from `std::bool_constant`.

However, aggregate classes must not have a base class [by definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178176/10774939), but when I use these types as `T` in `std::is_aggregate_v<T>`, I get `true`. So apparently, they are *not* derived from `std::bool_constant`?

So my question is:

Why is `std::is_aggregate_v<std::is_aggregate<void>>` true, at least with GCC and Clang? Doesn't the standard specify that `std::is_aggregate` is derived from `std::bool_constant`? If not, does this mean it leaves the value of the above line as an implementation detail?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
Non-virtual public base classes are allowed in C++17

Comment: Scroll down on the page you linked; read the _whole_ page ;)

Comment: Yeah, didn't realize that the linked text continues over multiple answers ;)

Comment: @x432ph It's usually a good idea to read all (or at least most) answers on a page; there's a reason we have a one-to-many Q&A model!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However, aggregate classes must not have a base class by definition

This is no longer true.  [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#1) defines an aggregate as

> An aggregate is an array or a class with
>
> - no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> - no private or protected non-static data members (Clause [class.access]),
> - no virtual functions, and
> - no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).
>
> [ Note: Aggregate initialization does not allow accessing protected and private base class' members or constructors.  — end note ]

There is no longer a condition that it does not have a base class like it did in C++14 and earlier.  As long as it has a public, non virtual base class that is now allowed.  This means that the type traits are now considered aggregates as long as the above holds true for them

Comment: And `std::is_aggregate` is new in C++17 so OP _must_ be using it 

Comment: [Pertinent link into the OP's source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786105/560648) (they didn't read it all)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, cool. I was about to write a comment on the top answer to have it edited but if there is a C++17 specific answer I'll just add a link to it so its easier to see that changes have happened.

Comment: Yep, there are answers for all standards published so far - OP over there should re-accept, ideally

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've updated the main answer to point to them to make it more obvious.

Comment: Delicious! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++17, classes with non-virtual, not private or protected bases are aggregates: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization